# Why am I unable to return an HTML element after awaiting a promise in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the following example the index.js calls the component DiffState.js which is supposed to wait for 2 seconds (to simulate an async operation) and then return an H1 element that says "hello".

index.js

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const DiffState = lazy(() => import("./DiffState"));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Suspense fallback={<h1>Waiting for component fallback.</h1>}>
    <DiffState />
  </Suspense>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

DiffState.js

```
import React from "react";

const DiffState = async () => {
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
  return <h1>hello</h1>;
};

export default DiffState;
```

What happens instead, for reasons I am unable to understand is that I end up with the following error:

> Error Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object
> Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an
> array instead.

this error occurs in the `DiffState` component btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From React's [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy):

> React.lazy takes a function that must call a dynamic import(). This must return a Promise which resolves to a module with a default export containing a React component

What happens in your example is that the `import` function receives (as argument) a function that returns `DiffState` - which is a `Promise`, rather than *a default export containing a React component*.
In other words, your `lazy` function renders into a `Promise` that's resolved into another `Promise`.

Hence, a component should be a **synchronous** function; although its content can still be updated:

```
const DiffState = () => {
  const [content, setContent] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setContent(<h1>hello</h1>);
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  return content;
};
```